# C++Builder: How to display accent in Android Application?

Tags: android, c++, c++builder

I am developping an Android application using C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin. As I create this app for a French company, I would like to display accent. For example, I have a String Grid with an Header text "Libellé". So I wrote this header title like this:

```
StringGrid1->ColumnByIndex(0)->Header = "Libellé"
```

But when I run the app, I have an unknown character ( a black diamond with a question mark).

How can I display accent in an Android?

Comment: Have you tried StringGrid1->ColumnByIndex(0)->Header = u8"Libellé"

Comment: Yes but it didn't change anything.

Comment: The `u8` prefix will encode the literal as UTF-8, but it will still be a `const char[]` array and treated as a `char*` pointer when assigned to `Header`. `Header` is declared as `UnicodeString`, which has no idea that the `char[]` data is UTF-8 and so will not convert non-ASCII characters to UTF-16 correctly. If you use a UTF-8 literal, you need to use `UTF8String` to ensure a proper conversion, eg: `Header = UTF8String(u8"Libellé");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the string literal as a **wide** literal (using `wchar_t` characters), not a **narrow** literal (using `char` characters).  Prefix the literal with `L` to make it wide:

```
StringGrid1->ColumnByIndex(0)->Header = L"Libellé";
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it!